# Specify $\sigma(f)$ for $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, \ x \rightarrow x^2$.

Tags: probability-theory

> Define $\sigma(f) := \{f^{-1}(B): B \in \mathscr B(\Bbb R)$} with $\mathscr B(\Bbb R)$ being the Borel algebra.
>
> Specify $\sigma(f)$ for $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, \ x \rightarrow x^2$.

My first intuition would be to do a case analysis and write something like $\sigma(f)$ $=$ $ \sqrt B$ for $B \ge 0$ and $-\sqrt B$ for $B \lt 0$, but I don't think that this makes sense when I talk about Borel sets, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\sigma(f)=f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$. But since you do not know the structure of a typical set in $\mathcal B$ (at least I don't know!) I think you should keep the answer in this form only.

But you can also give a generating algebra. First note that $Range(f)=[0,\infty)$. Now take any interval of the form $[a,b)$ where $a,b\in[0,\infty]$. Then $f^{-1}([a,b))=(-\sqrt{b},-\sqrt{a}]\cup [\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})=:I_{a,b}$.

You can check that collection of disjoint unions of $I_{a,b}$ as $a,b$ vary in $[0,\infty]$ is a generating algebra for $\sigma(f)$. Let this algebra be $\mathcal A$ then $\sigma(f)=\sigma(\mathcal A)$.

I don't know what else you can write specifically as an answer to this question.